# How do I install the intl extenuation for PHP on a Heroku hosted Laravel web application

Tags: laravel, heroku

I'm running a laravel app on heroku that is using Nova. I've gotten in deployed and everything seemed to work however I have a Product model that has a "price" field. The error message that I'm getting seems to suggest that there is an issue with the NumberFormatter::setAttribute() function in Symfony.

The error I receive when trying to render the main list of Product models is the following.

```
The Symfony\Component\Intl\NumberFormatter\NumberFormatter::setAttribute() method's argument $attr value 2 behavior is not implemented. The available attributes are: FRACTION_DIGITS, GROUPING_USED, ROUNDING_MODE. Please install the "into" extension for full localization capabilities"
```

Has anyone run into this error and what would solve it. I'm using niginx on heroku.

My Procfile is this.

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx_app.conf /public
```

and my nginx_app.conf has this in it.

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    internal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`composer require ext-intl` should do the trick to install the intl extension (which is available on Heroku, but [as an optional extension](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions)), or you can manually add this to the `require` section of `composer.json`:

```
"ext-intl": "*",
```